# postgres - granting SELECT inside SCHEMA

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have created a database, role and schema with this script:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- set variables ---------------------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\set dbname keycloak
\set schemaname :dbname
\set rolename :dbname

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- create ROLE and Database ----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE ROLE :rolename WITH LOGIN ;
CREATE DATABASE :dbname WITH OWNER :rolename ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- connect to DB, create SCHEMA & set privileges -------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\c :dbname
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC ;
CREATE SCHEMA :schemaname AUTHORIZATION :rolename ;
ALTER ROLE :rolename SET search_path=:schemaname ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA :schemaname TO :rolename ;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE :dbname FROM PUBLIC ;
```

This all seems to work in regards to what the `keycloak` ROLE can do on the `keycloak` Database.

Now I want to GRANT SELECT to a ROLE `keycloak_reader` ON ALL TABLES inside that SCHEMA keycloak. Further more that role should be granted to other roles (which should inherit those SELECT ability [ideally including the search_path]).

I tried

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE keycloak TO keycloak_reader ;
\c keycloak
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA keycloak TO keycloak_reader ;
ALTER ROLE keycloak SET search_path=keyckloak ;
```

I can connect, but can not SELECT anything (permission denied). Neither as `keycloak_reader`, nor as any of the roles which a members of `keycloak_reader` group.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `grant usage on schema keyckloak to keycloak_reader;`

Comment: thx, that is a step forward indeed @Melkij . However the `search_path` value ist not inherited apparently. Any idea, whether that is possible?

if you post this as an answer, rather then a comment, I would be happy tp mark it as solution.

Comment: seems you can not inherit the search_path (as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810621/postgresql-can-i-inherit-search-path-variable-from-a-group-role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to permissions at the level of an object in the database (table, sequence, function, etc.), the user should have `USAGE` privilege on this schema to actually use any object within schema.

So you need to add:

```
grant usage on schema keyckloak to keycloak_reader;
```

It's pretty easy to miss, the error message will only say you don't have permissions on schema if you specify the table name along with the schema (not relying on search_path).

---

Configuration settings for a role cannot be inherited. This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html):

> Note that role-specific defaults attached to roles without LOGIN privilege are fairly useless, since they will never be invoked.